# What happens when some recipient do not have Group Messaging?

Tags: messages, settings, ios

I'm confused about what participants see and where their messages are sent, when I send a message to multiple users. I understand that when everyone is on iMessage, all participants see all other participants, and all messages go to everyone.

But I'm not clear how things break down if some participants are not on iMessage. I gather (and would like to have confirmed) that:

(1) If Group Messaging is not enabled on my iOS device (or MMS Messaging is disabled), (a) each participant who is not in iMessage is split into a distinct SMS thread, unconnected to the original message while (b) all participants on iMessage remain in an iMessage conversation together.

(2) If Group Messaging is enabled on my iOS device, a group MMS session is created, which behaves much like an iMessage group: all messages go to everyone who also has group messaging enabled on their devices.

What's not clear to me is what happens when Group Messaging is enabled on my iOS device when

(A) some participants have iOS devices with Group Messaging disabled, or when

(B) some participants have non-iOS devices without group messaging or without the feature enabled (or without MMS at all).

Will users in these cases see a group conversation taking place? Will their replies go to everyone or just to me?

Comment: As far I know, you making a group is just for your connivance. The system will still send message to each named (in the group) individual regardless if the have the group on or off. They can choose a reply to you or reply to all.

Comment: @Buscar웃: The question is what happens on the recipients' end: what do they see, and what happens if they don't (explicitly) "choose"?